# Servlet [cxf] in web application [/firstws] threw load() exception. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet

Tags: java, web-services, maven, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to run a web service on tomcat server at localhost.Can anyone please help me out.

Maven clean and Maven install are successful. But while launching the Tomcat server the error pops up.The error message is:

War file is generated in the Target directory cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.2jar is present in the directory.

Tried deleting the server and restarting the server. 
There is a warning in this file, says "**src/main/webapp/services not found**"

Index.jsp

```
 <html>
   <body>
       <!--the warning is below line at href attribute--!>
       <h2>Hello World! <a href="/services"> available services </a>
      </h2>
   </body>
    </html>
```

POM.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
            http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
           <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
           <groupId>com.vasu.sample</groupId>
           <artifactId>firstws</artifactId>
           <packaging>war</packaging>
           <version>1.0</version>
           <name>firstws Maven Webapp</name>
           <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>



             <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>

                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>

                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>generate-sources</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/generated</sourceRoot>
                                <wsdlOptions>                                   
                                    <wsdlOption>
                <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-
                                   INF/wsdl/CustomerOrders.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    </wsdlOption>
                                </wsdlOptions>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>

                </plugin>

            </plugins>

            <finalName>firstws</finalName>
        </build>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Jetty is needed if you're are not using the CXFServlet -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

    </project>
```

web.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

      <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
       version="2.5">
   <display-name>cxf</display-name>
     <servlet>
        <description>Apache CXF Endpoint</description>
         <display-name>cxf</display-name>
         <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
   </session-config>
 </web-app>
```

cxf-servlet.xml:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
          xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core" 
         xmlns:soap="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://cxf.apache.org/core 
          http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
          http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap 
          http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/soap.xsd 
           http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

        <jaxws:endpoint id="customerOrderid" address="/customerOrders"
            wsdlLocation="WEB-INF/wsdl/customerOrders.wsdl"  
            implementor="com.bharath.ws.train.imp.CustomersOrdersWS"
            serviceName="customersOrders:CustomerOrdersService" 
            xmlns:customersOrders="http://train.ws.bharath.com/" >
         </jaxws:endpoint>
    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:features>
            <cxf:logging /> 
        </cxf:features>
    </cxf:bus>
   </beans>
```

Comment: make sure
src/main/webapp/services is in your classpath

Comment: I added the src/main/webapp/services to classpath. The error remains same.Shows me the HTTP status 404 -/services when accessing http://localhost:9999/services.

Comment: @Adeel Ahmed can you help me with this.